# Python: Print results of a parsing function in the function itself, or have the function return the result and print it an external calling function?

Tags: python, loops, parsing, return

My question may be a basic one, but I haven't found any answers. My goal is to write a program that parses new entries in a text file and outputs them whenever the line has greater than 5 chars. Consider the following code which works as intended:

```
from pygtail import Pygtail

def parse(input):
    for line in input:
        if len(line) > 5:
            print(line)


def main():
    tail = Pygtail('D:\\test.txt')
    while True:
        parse(tail)       

main()
```

However if I want the parse function to return a value and the main function to print what's returned, I get `None` over and over again in the output. Bad code:

```
from pygtail import Pygtail

def parse(input):
    for line in input:
        if len(line) > 5:
            return line


def main():
    tail = Pygtail('D:\\test.txt')
    while True:
        x = parse(tail)
        print(x)


main()
```

I understand that `None` is the default return value, but what I don't get is that when I try and save a longer line in the file, it doesn't seem to matter and will always keep printing out `None`. Could it somehow be messing up the file's offset? It seems to me that both versions of the code should behave the same way but they don't. Could anyone shed some light on why this is?

Comment: That was an error pasting the code. The return statement is correctly indented in my actual code.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you print in your `parse()` function, you print repeatedly for all lines of length > 5.  When you `return` from your function, you end its execution on the *first* iteration that has `len(line) > 5`, which is what's causing you to lose results.

Comment: So how would you suggest implementing this with a return statement in the parse function. I've heard it's better practice to have functions like this return rather than print.

Comment: @lhome1212 - The way you've written it you can't just swap `return` for `print`.  If you want to return all the lines that are longer than five characters you can append them to a list outside of your `for` loop, then return the list after the loop has completed.  Otherwise, you need to rethink what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic use for a `generator`.  This is a function-like item that will  return a single result each time it's called; on each successive call, it will pick up where it left off.  You iterate over the result.

```
def parse(input):
    for line in input:
        if len(line) > 5:
            yield line

def main():
    tail = Pygtail('D:\\test.txt')
    for x in parse(tail):
        print(x)
```

You've almost certainly used `range` like this.

Comment: Yes this can work! I'm new to python so I've never really used generators before, but this is making sense.

Comment: Excellent!  I know it's a little ahead of what you've likely learned so far, but it's so fitting, I hoped you'd stretch a little.